# C# WinForm DataGridView with autocomplete ComboBox column supplied with dynamic data from database source

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, autocomplete

I need to add a ComboBox column in my datagrdiview (winform) with these simple functionalities:

- Autocomplete
- Loads items from database dinamically, based on typed value (all items starting with typed text)
- Possibility to insert new value (type text with no match on database values)

I tried to set datasource of myComboBoxColumn at KeyDown event of editing control (the combobox) with no success.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Properties you need to write for ComboBox Column 
1. column1.AutoCompleteMode=AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
2. column1.AutoCompleteSource=AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;